# Laravel Не могу подключить Request в экшн: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу подключить Request в экшн контроллера для прохождения валидации.
Браузер выдает ошибку `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` - циклическая переадресация.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Channel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{        
    public function add(Request $request) 
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
             'name' => 'required|min:3'
         ]);        
         dd($request->all());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Причина Циклической переадресации скорее всего какая-нить миддлвара, надо роуты смотреть